# Does Spring Security go well with custom authentication and authorization code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working on a REST service provider web application with Java + Spring and I wonder if I can fuse my in-house authentication and authorization code with Spring Security?

To be more specific, I have two methods (that I like to keep):

```
User authenticate(String username, String password) { ... }
boolean authorize(User user, String resource) { ... }
```

In this scenario, a REST API is a resource and the second method verifies whether it can be called by the user or not.

My question is if I switch to Spring Security then should I give in to it and annotate my methods with user names and role names!? Or is there a way that I can keep my way of thinking (that REST APIs are resources and annotating them with user names and role names is like hard-coding ACL)?

I know my question is somewhat vague but I've been struggling with it for some time now and I'll be really grateful if someone can give a straight answer.

Comment: Short answer is yes. Spring Security allows plugging in any authentication and authorization framework, subject to conformance with certain contracts. You will find plenty of guidance on these aspects on StackOverflow if you search for them separately.

Comment: @manish Thanks, but I'm having a hard time finding the right keywords to search. Could you please be a little more specific?

Comment: Custom authentication schemes (including those that authenticate users against proprietary solutions) can be implemented using an [`AuthenticationProvider`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-authenticationprovider). Custom authorization schemes can be implemented by providing an implementation of [`RoleVoter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#authz-custom-voter).

Comment: @manish Thanks, I'll be happy to mark these information as answer if you feel like posting them as one

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your own authentication manager with password encoder.

Below is a post where I posted some questions about it a while ago. It's not an exact answer for you but it will lead you down the right track.

[debug spring security authentication-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212595/debug-spring-security-authentication-manager/20238851#20238851)

At the time I did it xml style but I'm sure you can change this to a java config style.

It definitely worked foe me!

Answer (score 0):

Spring security also very useful for providing authentication and authorization to the REST URLs. We no need to specify any custom implementations.

First, you need to specify the entry-point-ref to restAuthenticationEntryPoint in your security configuration as below.

```
 <security:http pattern="/api/**" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" create-session="stateless" >

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/userList" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/managerList" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="preAuthFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
</security:http>
```

Implementation for the restAuthenticationEntryPoint might be as below.

```
 @Component
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

   public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException ) throws IOException {
      response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized" );
   }
}
```

After this you need to specify RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter. It contains the RequestHeader key. This is basically used for identifying the user`s authentication. Generally RequestHeader carries this information while making the REST calls. 
For example consider below code

```
   <bean id="preAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="principalRequestHeader" value="Authorization"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
  </bean>
```

Here,

```
<property name="principalRequestHeader" value="Authorization"/>
```

"Authorization" is the the key presented the incoming request. It holds the required user`s authentication information.
Also you need to configure the PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider to fulfill our requirement.

```
   <bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
<property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
  <bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"
      class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="authenticationService"/>
  </bean>
</property>
</bean>
```

This code will work for securing the REST urls by means of Authentication and authorization without any custom implementations.

My suggestion is go with Spring-AOP for custom authentication and authorization, if you want custom implementation for authentication and authorization which works similar to the spring security.

For Complete code please find the below link:

https://github.com/srinivas1918/spring-rest-security

I hope that, i understood your question.